# SKAT test statistic differences

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing, genetics

I am trying to implement the SKAT test statistic(from the paper [Rare-Variant Association Testing for Sequencing Data with the Sequence Kernel Association Test](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3135811/)). According to the paper the test statistic is

$$ Q = (y-\hat{\mu})'K(y-\hat{\mu})$$

where, $K = GWG'$, $G$ being the genotype matrix, $W$ a diagonal weight matrix with weights $\sqrt{w_i} = Beta(MAF_i, 1, 25)$, and $(y -\hat{\mu})$ the residuals from some base model.

Here are the results from the example in the SKAT package.

```
data(SKAT.example)
attach(SKAT.example)

> obj<-SKAT_Null_Model(y.c ~ 1, out_type="C")
> SKAT(Z, obj)$Q
         [,1]
[1,] 234803.8
```

While here are the results from my implementation.

```
> maf.vec  <- colMeans(Z) / 2 
> res.user <- y.c - mean(y.c)
> 
> all(abs(res.user - obj$res) < 10^-12)
[1] TRUE
> 
> W <- diag(dbeta(maf.vec, 1, 25)^2)
> t(res.user) %*% Z %*% W %*% t(Z) %*% res.user
         [,1]
[1,] 602702.9
```

Why are they different?